# Enlarge person and mythic

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Why does mythic enlarge person have a maximum size of huge when enlarge person has no such restriction?

I assume its to prevent shenanigans about becoming too big, but then why doesn't enlarge person have a similar restriction to say large?

Why do both seem to assume that the starting size is always medium?  There have been small playable races in the first Core rule book. I feel like the spell is poorly worded and has never been properly updated.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is asking? There are three ways this question could be read (and hence, three different, incompatible ways of answering it). They are: 1) “Have the designers said why they designed it this way?”, 2) “What does everyone think is the reason this works this way?”, 3) “The design is stupid and poorly worded.” Which one is this question intended to be read as saying? If none of those, what is it supposed to be asking?