# Does Enlarge Person(Non-Mythic) have a maximum size

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, creature-size, mythic-adventures

From [Mythic Enlarge Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/):

> You can increase the target’s size by up to two size categories, to a maximum of Huge.

The text for the non-mythic version of the spell has no similar restriction in the rules.

Assuming that Mythic Spells are supposed to be enhanced versions of their non-mythic counterparts, is there anything capping the size of a creature affected by non-mythic Enlarge Person, assuming he starts at Large or higher, and is Humanoid?

Comment: [This Question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84223/enlarge-person-and-mythic) is related, but was closed with no answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No

The non-mythic spell is *not* capped, and on humanoids of at least Huge size the size alteration will be greater than that of its mythic counterpart.  Mythic spells are *not* always better than their nonmythic counterparts, just as higher level spells are often inferior to lower level ones.

Answer (score 2):

Technically no limit beyond the stated size categories, but it comes down to the fact that enlarge person has a limited amount of targets, which means that there is a limited size range which is possible.

Answer (score -2):

Within the base spell it defines the caps. Humanoid, and spell does not stack…

Good luck finding a HUMANOID that is Huge (or Bigger) that isn’t already effected by a magical size altering effect.

Those 2 stipulations is what makes the Mythic version more powerful that the standard.

Most Humanoids are Small or Medium.
Only one instance of size altering magic can be applied.

Thus, with Enlarge person, a human could be Large. OR with Mythic EP, the human could be Huge.

Similarly, the halfling could become Medium or Large.

Comment: How is it really different than [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/110275/10642)?

Comment: Also, the snarky condescending tone is not a positive contribution to your answer.